# How do I write a Django query that joins two tables without a common column and uses a formula to calculate time?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql, join

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I want to write a Django query that returns instances of my Article model but I want to write the query where two tables are joined in which there isn't a common key between them.  The PostGres query would look like ...

```
select a.* 
    FROM myproj_statbyhour h, 
         myproj_article a 
    WHERE h.hour_of_day = extract(hour from a.created_on + 1000 * interval '1 second') 
          and h.total_score < 1000;
```

The models in question look like

```
class Article(models.Model):
    objects = ArticleManager()
    title = models.TextField(default='', null=False)
    ...
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, default=datetime.now)


class StatByHour(models.Model):
    total_score = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, null=False)
    ...
    hour_of_day = IntegerField(
        null=False,
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(23),
            MinValueValidator(0)
        ]
    )
```

I have no idea how to do this, especially how to write the "h.hour_of_day = extract(hour from a.created_on + 1000 * interval '1 second')" part.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [extract functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#datetimefield-extracts).

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractHour

Article.objects.annotate(
    hour=ExtractHour('created_on'),
).filter(hour=stat_by_hour.hour_of_day)
```

However something you need to be concerned about are timezones. The [documentation at the end of this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#datetimefield-extracts) provides a few ways you can handle it, though if you're trying to aggregate all the data that might be a bit more difficult.

Comment: Thanks.  How do I replicate the "interval '1 second'" part of the PostGres query using the annotation you list?

Comment: You'd have to create your own function to do that. Look at how `ExtractHour` is implemented then implement your own with: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions